# How to use Spek

Tags: java, android, testing, kotlin

I tried [this sample](https://github.com/nhekfqn/kotlin-spek-maven-sample.git), but it raises a syntax error. Is there any other way to test Kotlin? For example, with JUnit or Spek?

```
import kotlin.test.assertEquals
import org.jetbrains.spek.api.Spek

class BlaherSpecs: Spek() {{
    given("Let's test Blaher") {
        var blaher = Blaher()

        on("Blaher blah") {
            val blah = blaher.blah()

            it("should be Blah!") {
                assertEquals("Blah1!", blah)
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

[image: IDE with errors]

Comment: Be more specific, what you want to achieve

Comment: At the very least, you need to put the code in a method.

Answer (score 3):

You cut and paste an old syntax from `spek` site :) you need *function name* before the second bracket as the error suggests: use `{ init {` instead of `{{`

```
import kotlin.test.assertEquals
import org.jetbrains.spek.api.Spek

class BlaherSpecs: Spek() { init {
    given("Let's test Blaher") {
        var blaher = Blaher()

        on("Blaher blah") {
            val blah = blaher.blah()

            it("should be Blah!") {
                assertEquals("Blah1!", blah)
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use any test framework with Kotlin in exactly the same way as in Java. A sample project using Kotlin, Maven and JUnit can be found [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-examples/tree/master/maven/hello-world).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you using 0.1-SNAPSHOT version. Please try current version [0.1.188](http://repository.jetbrains.com/simple/spek/org/jetbrains/spek/spek/)